# HDMI and a cracked screen

Tags: windows-8, boot, laptop, display, hdmi

So recently my laptop screen was broken pretty badly, and the entire screen is covered in white and black spots and lines, so it's impossible for me to see anything. So for the past few days, I've been hooking it up to a second screen via HDMI, which was working fine, until my computer crashed. So now, with no hard drive enabled, my computer wont boot up all the way. And of course, my computer didn't send images to the second screen until after booting up. so obviously I cant fix it without seeing anything, but I can't see anything without fixing it. Is there anyway to connect to a second screen before my computer boots up? I've tried the FN+ F4 keys, along with FN + F5 but nothings working. My Laptop is a windows 8, HP Altec. A6 Vision

Comment: How do you expect your laptop to boot without a hdd?

Comment: @Ramhound It is possible to boot a computer into what is called the BIOS  and that would be before running a partition of a hdd. Furthermore, it is possible for a computer to boot without a hard drive and get all the way into an operating system, and there exist CDs that are bootable for example Windows CDs. One can also boot off a USB stick.  But perhaps you've heard of booting off a Windows CD so yeah it's possible it will boot whether useful or not. But clearly what he wants is a screen to for example see the BIOS and i'm sure he'll use a HDD anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting an external keyboard/mouse via USB and booting the computer with the lid closed. This will often make a computer act like it's connected to a dock, forcing the external monitor to be the primary display.